Connection between the sum of the divisor function and overlapping partitions of n
Define $a(n) = \sum_{k = 1}^n \left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor$. This is sequence A006218 in the On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.
On the OIES page, Jon Perry commented that this sequence is the

Area covered by overlapped partitions of n, i.e., sum of maximum
values of the k-th part of a partition of n into k parts.

I'm having trouble understanding or finding a reference for this fact. Is anyone able to explain this comment?

This comment makes sense if you interpret the parts of a partition to be in non-increasing order. In that case, any partition into $k$ parts has the $k$th part (the smallest part) being of size at most $\lfloor \tfrac{n}{k} \rfloor$, and furthermore, you can achieve this maximum.

Thanks! I'm especially curious how this sequence can be interpreted as the “area covered by overlapped partitions of n." Any thoughts about that?

It's what you get if you put all the Young diagrams of size $n$ together. Since the $k$th row has $\lfloor \tfrac{n}{k} \rfloor$ squares, the total area is equal to the given sum.
